# How to create a user-defined language in Notepad++ based on an existing language?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I frequently work with files that have an extension of .ebs. This is a language based on vbscript with a number of new keywords.

Currently I set notepad++ to just use the built-in vb highlighting for files with extension .vbs. Works ok, but the custom keywords do not get highlighted.

I would like to create a user-defined language for the .ebs files but base it off of the built-in vb language.

Is this possible? I searched but the built-in languages do not have an associated .xml file to copy and change.

Answer (score 15):

All highlights are situated in \langs.model.xml and \stylers.model.xml.

Copy the one xml you want to base on and edit it the way you like.

Comment: On my my install there is a vb.xml file in that folder but it only includes AutoComplete information.

Comment: Ok, you are to edit langs.model.xml and stylers.model.xml. First file defines syntax and second - highlighting style.

Comment: @Roy, well, does this answer your question? :)

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers are correct and very helpful. Here is a slight update.

In Notepad++ 6.6.9 the xml files are called "stylers.xml" and "langs.xml" and are located in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ (at least on Windows 7 computer).