# Notepad++ shortcut to change document's language || Auto-closing tags in custom language

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight some XML nodes and attributes according to their name, but didn't find a way to (except writing my own lexer according to [Extending language definitions (for code highlighting) in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575865/extending-language-definitions-for-code-highlighting-in-notepad) but I don't want to go that deep).

So, I made a custom language for the syntax highlighting, but I lost the auto-closing tags (like when I type the `>` of `<foo:bar`, Npp auto closes the tag and writes `<foo:bar></foo:bar>`.

So in order to do the highlighting and have the auto-closing function, I switch between languages:
I have a XML file and write it in `XML Language` mode. Then, when I want to highlight, I switch to my custom language: `foo-xml Language`.

Doing so with point & click is a pain.

**Is there a way to have a shortcut for switching to some precise language?**
Like `Ctrl+1` to switch to XML, and `Ctrl+2` to switch to `foo-xml`.

Or

**Is there a way to activate the auto-closing function in a custom language?**

I also happily accept any answer that allows me to "mix" the two languages, and *highlight some node's names according to a custom node names list.*

Comment: Your question is not about XML (the markup language itself), and therefore the XML tag is not applicable. (The fact your syntax highlighting happens to be related to XML is not relevant.) Your question is simply about NP++. Please use tags that are applicable to your question, and read the description of the tag. Using tags appropriately not only helps get you answers more quickly, but it also correctly classifies the question for use in searches. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, sorry, I wrongly added it because of the auto-closing tag part. I'll keep that in mind next time. ☺

Comment: No problem. The mention of "auto-closing tag" doesn't make it related to the topic of XML; it's simply something that's also part of NPP. XML relates to the actual use of the markup language itself, and you're not asking about that topic. (Read the description of any tag before using it, if you're not certain it applies to your question.)