# For NotePad++ how can I extend the language definition for XML?

Tags: xml, notepad++, syntax-highlighting, vxml

This question is somewhat similar to a question about TWIG [Extending language definitions (for code highlighting) in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575865/extending-language-definitions-for-code-highlighting-in-notepad).

I'm hoping to extend the definitions that Notepad++ uses for XML to include keywords with some highlighting for [vxml](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/) and [grxml](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/) in order to help myself and other developers manage development of vxml applications.

So far all I can do is expand the autocomplete list by editing the plugins\APIs\xml.xml file. I would like to highlight vxml keywords with one color and grxml keywords with another, but unless I've missed something, it doesn't seem like this can be accomplished using just the UI language creator, or by editing the stylers.xml and lang.xml.

Essentially, I just need to be able to add two categories of wordstyles to the  XML definition and populate them with words. Any help that any of you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just tweaked some of your formatting.