# Highlight CSS codes in PHP files in Notepad++

Tags: css, notepad++

I have a PHP file, which Notepad++ correctly highlights any PHP code. Inside of this file, I have some Javascript, which is properly recognized between the `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` tags.

However, I have some CSS codes that not being properly highlighted in PHP files.
Where I can do highlight CSS codes in PHP files same JavaScript codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here: [Extending language definitions (for code highlighting) in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575865/extending-language-definitions-for-code-highlighting-in-notepad)

You should maybe try this: https://github.com/Banane9/notepadplusplus-twig

Comment: Unfortunately, I not found answer in that links, thank you.