# Notepad++ File Styling

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to copy my PHP language styling to a new file type and have it applied to specific file, even when there is no `<?` tags in the page.

I view log files on a daily basis. Today while viewing a file I inadvertently  added `<?` to the start of the file.  The log was then formatted as PHP and became much easier to read.

Is it possible to copy the PHP styling to a new Language Type (logFile) and have the styling applied to specific files even if the file doesn't contain `<?` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new style based on PHP style please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878241/how-to-create-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad-based-on-an-existing-language) SO question.

But if you want a quicker and easier (in my opinion) solution I propose you  this alternative: instead of creating a new language style based on PHP you can associate one or more new file extension(s) to the existing PHP style.

To do this use the menu "***Settings***"/"***Style configurator...***" and specify your extension(s) in the **"*User ext.***" textbox:

[image]

If you want to add more than one extension just use a space as separator: "ext1 ext2".

Click ***"Save & Close"*** button.

Now if you open a file that has one of the new extension(s), Notepad++ should style it using PHP rules even if there are no `<?` tags in the file.

Comment: Thanks. I've applied this to the file extension and opened a new file in Notepadd++. The style is only applied if I add `<?` or `<?php` to the start of the new file. Is there anyway to do this without the tags ?

Comment: @Tom So the style is not applied only when you create a new file from scratch? If you open an existing file (having the custom extension you added in Style Configurator) does it get the correct style?